# BLE connection buffersize to packet length

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, buffer

I am currently working on a graduation project where I want to transmit a sessiontoken using BLE. On the server side I am using Node.js and Bleno to create the connection. After the client subscribes to the notification, the server will push the token.
A small part of the code is:

```
const buf1 = Buffer.from(info, 'utf8');

updateValueCallback(buf1);
```

At this step, I am using nRF Connect to check if everything is working. My intention works, except I see that only the first 20 characters are transferred. (As much as the packet size)

My question concerns the buffer size. Will, when I finally connect to an Android app, the whole string be transmitted? In this case the underlying protocols will cut the string and reassemble it on the other side. In this case the buffer size doesn't matter. Or must I negotiate the MTU to be the size of the string. In other words must the buffersize be the size of the transmitted package?

In the case the buffer is smaller than the whole string, can the whole string still be transmitted with it?

Answer (score 1):

GATT requires that a notification is maximum MTU - 3 bytes long. The default MTU is 23 so hence the maximum modification value length is 20 bytes by default. By negotiating a larger MTU you can send longer notifications (if your BLE stack supports that).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Bleno but all the stack that I have used I needed to slice the data myself 20 bytes at the time. And on receiver side collect them and put them together again.

The stacks have been good to buffer the data and transmit it one chunk at the time. So I have looped the function (as your updateValueCallback()) until all the slices of my data was done.

Hope it works for you.